# Three.js update object's matrix and scale?

Tags: three.js

I need to transform my objects from normal coordinates to relative coordinate on a globe. I have computed a very nice transformation matrix and set it to the object like below.
     Object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
     Object.matrix= my matrix;
It works fine. But later when I need to perform a scale on z. Nothing happened, I guess it's because I turn off auto update. So I called updateMatrix() after changing the scale. The scale did change, but the transformation matrix changed backed to the default one.

Did I do anything wrong?

By the way, if I don't use matrix, and change the up vector of the object. The value never changes. It's always 0,1,0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate` to `true` when modifying `object.matrix`.

Comment: Is this still the case? I see in WebGLRenderer that it calls `scene.updateMatrixWorld()` which calls `updateMatrixWorld( true )` on all of it's children, which seems to force update all child world matrices, therefore if we are calling `renderer.render()` every tick, we do not need to set `object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate` to `true` every time we modify `object.matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use object matrix, you set the matrixAutoUpdate to false, here is the code for transform, rotation in x,y,z sequence, then do scale, last transform.

```
rM = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(rV.y), new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(rV.x));
rM.premultiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(rV.z));
object.matrix.copy(rM).scale(sV).setPosition(tV);
```

here you cannot use the `updateMatrix` for it will update matrix according the object posiiton, scale, rotation info which were not changed when your set the matrix.

Comment: Do not set `matrixAutoUpdate = false` unless you are familiar with the inner-workings of the library and understand the consequences of doing so.

Comment: @WestLangley What are the consequences? I am building a lib on top of Three, where I'm calculating matrices outside of Three, and I want to apply them to all the objects. Is there a bad consequence?

Comment: @trusktr Only set `matrixAutoUpdate = false` if the object is known to be static. More info [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3153).

Comment: I also set scene.autoUpdate to false. All objects have custom matrixWorlds. Are there any consequences of that?